# AttributeError How can i change the color of the circle Kv

Tags: python, kivy

im having this message: " AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'. Did you mean: '**setattr**'?"
im trying to build a code to the game Connect4, and need to change the color of the circle once the player click in the button

im trying to build a code to the game Connect4, and need to change the color of the circle once the player click in the button, the color will be select by another value "X", this part of code im just trying to make work 1 circle from Coluna A1

My python code:

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
class Tela(Widget):
    x = 1

    #Cor Players
    player1 = (1,0,0,1)
    player2 = (0,0,1,1)

    #Coluna A
    colunA1 = (1,1,1,1)
    A1 = 0
    colunA2 = (1,1,1,1)
    A2 = 0
    colunA3 = (1,1,1,1)
    A3 = 0
    colunA4 = (1,1,1,1)
    A4 = 0
    colunA5 = (1,1,1,1)
    A5 = 0
    colunA6 = (1,1,1,1)
    A6 = 0
    def botaocolunA(self):
        if self.A1 == 0:
            if self.x %2 ==0:
                self.ids.AA1.rgba = self.player2
                x = x+1
            else:
                self.ids.AA1.rgba = self.player1
                x = x+1
        
        
    #Coluna B
    colunB1 = (1,1,1,1)
    #Coluna C
    colunC1 = (1,1,1,1)
    #Coluna D
    colunD1 = (1,1,1,1)
    #Coluna E
    colunE1 = (1,1,1,1)
    #Coluna F
    colunF1 = (1,1,1,1)
    #Coluna G
    colunG1 = (1,1,1,1)



class AulaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = " Lig4 "
        Window.size = (670,500)
        return Tela()
    
AulaApp().run()
```

Kivy Code:

```
<Tela>
    canvas:
        Color:  
            rgba: 0.1,0.1,0.1,1
        Rectangle:            
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: (5,470)
            size: (100,40)
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,1,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: (100,470)
            size: (100,40)
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: (5,410)
            size: (195,60)
        Color:
            rgba: 0.6,0.6,0.6,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: (200, 5)
            size: (670,900)

        #Coluna A
        Color:
            rgba: root.colunA1
            id: AA1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (210,5)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunA2
        Ellipse:
            pos: (210,80)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunA3
        Ellipse:
            pos: (210,155)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunA4
        Ellipse:
            pos: (210,230)
            size: (70,70)
        
        Color:
            rgba: root.colunA5
        Ellipse:
            pos: (210,305)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunA6
        Ellipse:
            pos: (210,380)
            size: (70,70)
        # Coluna B
        Color:
            rgba: root.colunB1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (290,5)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunB1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (290,80)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunB1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (290,155)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunB1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (290,230)
            size: (70,70)
        
        Color:
            rgba: root.colunB1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (290,305)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunB1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (290,380)
            size: (70,70)
        # Coluna C
        Color:
            rgba: root.colunC1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (370,5)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunC1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (370,80)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunC1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (370,155)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunC1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (370,230)
            size: (70,70)
        
        Color:
            rgba: root.colunC1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (370,305)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunC1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (370,380)
            size: (70,70)
        # Coluna D
        Color:
            rgba: root.colunD1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (450,5)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunD1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (450,80)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunD1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (450,155)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunD1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (450,230)
            size: (70,70)
        
        Color:
            rgba: root.colunD1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (450,305)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunD1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (450,380)
            size: (70,70)
        # Coluna E
        Color:
            rgba: root.colunE1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (530,5)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunE1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (530,80)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunE1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (530,155)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunE1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (530,230)
            size: (70,70)
        
        Color:
            rgba: root.colunE1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (530,305)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunE1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (530,380)
            size: (70,70)
        #Coluna F
        Color:
            rgba: root.colunF1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (610,5)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunF1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (610,80)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunF1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (610,155)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunF1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (610,230)
            size: (70,70)
        
        Color:
            rgba: root.colunF1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (610,305)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunF1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (610,380)
            size: (70,70)
        #Coluna G
        Color:
            rgba: root.colunG1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (690,5)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunG1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (690,80)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunG1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (690,155)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunG1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (690,230)
            size: (70,70)
        
        Color:
            rgba: root.colunG1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (690,305)
            size: (70,70)

        Color:
            rgba: root.colunG1
        Ellipse:
            pos: (690,380)
            size: (70,70)
        
    # Botao Coluna A
    Button: 
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: (1,1,0,1)
        pos: (210,460)
        size: (70,30)
        on_release: root.botaocolunA()
         


        
    Label:
        text: "Player 1"
        pos: (5,470)
        size: (100,40)
    Label:
        text: "Player 2"
        pos: (100,470)
        size: (100,40)
    Label:
        text: "Placar:"
        pos: (50, 440)
        size: (100, 40)
    Label:
        text: "X"
        pos: (50,410)
        size: (100,40)
    Label:
        text: "0"
        pos: (30, 410)
        size: (100,40)
        id: placarvermelho

    Label:
        text: "0"
        pos: (70,410)
        size:(100,40)
        id: placarazul
    
    

    
    

    

    Button:
        text: "Jogar"
        pos: 10,70
        size: 100,50`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use kivy properties to re-render every time variables change, for example:

```py
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, NumericProperty
class Tela(Widget):
    x = NumericProperty(1)

    #Cor Players
    player1 = ListProperty([1,0,0,1])
    player2 = ListProperty([0,0,1,1])

    #Coluna A
    colunA1 = ListProperty([1,1,1,1])
    A1 = NumericProperty(0)
    colunA2 = ListProperty([1,1,1,1])
    A2 = NumericProperty(0)
    colunA3 = ListProperty([1,1,1,1])
    A3 = NumericProperty(0)
    colunA4 = ListProperty([1,1,1,1])
    A4 = NumericProperty(0)
    colunA5 = ListProperty([1,1,1,1])
    A5 = NumericProperty(0)
    colunA6 = ListProperty([1,1,1,1])
    A6 = NumericProperty(0)
    def botaocolunA(self):
        if self.A1 == 0:
            if self.x %2 ==0:
                self.ids.AA1.rgba = self.player2
                x = x+1
            else:
                self.ids.AA1.rgba = self.player1
                x = x+1
        
        
    #Coluna B
    colunB1 = ListProperty([1,1,1,1])
    #Coluna C
    colunC1 = ListProperty([1,1,1,1])
    #Coluna D
    colunD1 = ListProperty([1,1,1,1])
    #Coluna E
    colunE1 = ListProperty([1,1,1,1])
    #Coluna F
    colunF1 = ListProperty([1,1,1,1])
    #Coluna G
    colunG1 = ListProperty([1,1,1,1])



class AulaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = " Lig4 "
        Window.size = (670,500)
        return Tela()
    
AulaApp().run()
```

Or, you can use [KivyMD](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.1/) to add customizable widgets